# Python ssl.wrap_socket blocking

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, networking, pyopenssl

I am trying to implement an SSL connection in Python 2.7.10, but when I call wrap_socket() after accept() it appears to be blocking.  I can't see why and looking at the documentation it doesn't talk about.

Settings class is:

class SSLSocketSettings:

```
def __init__(self, sslVersion = None, ciphers = None, certFile = None
    , privateKey = None, serverSide = False):

    self._sslVersion = sslVersion
    self._ciphers = ciphers
    self._certFile = None
    self._privateKey = None
    self._serverSide = serverSide
```

accept is:

```
def Accept(self, timeout):
    if self._rawSocketHandle == None: return None

    readFDS = [ self._rawSocketHandle ]
    read, _, _ = select.select(readFDS, [], [], timeout)

    if  self._rawSocketHandle in read:
        try:
            newHandle, _ = self._rawSocketHandle.accept()

            newSettings = self._settings
            newSettings._serverSide = True

            newSocket = SSLSocket(self._socketType, newSettings, newHandle) 
            return newSocket

        except socket.error:
            return None
```

Constructor for SSLSocket is:

```
def __init__(self, socketType, settings, socketHandle = None):
    self._rawSocketHandle = socketHandle

    self._settings = settings

    if self._rawSocketHandle == None:
        try:
            self._rawSocketHandle = socket.socket(socketType
                , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except OSError:
            raise SystemError("Failed to create return socket")     

    sslObject = ssl.wrap_socket(self._rawSocketHandle
        , settings._privateKey, settings._certFile
        , self._settings._serverSide, do_handshake_on_connect = True)
```

Any advice would be gratefully accepted.

My code was based on [The Python manual for SSL](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/ssl.html)